# how to ignore/skip white spaces when reading from a textfile using string getline in c++

Tags: c++, string, whitespace, getline

Hi I am trying to develop a program which can read from a text file for example

```
Edward Elric : 2000 300 3000 300
Super Trunks : 100 300 4000 900
Saitama Genos:
Goku Black: 12 333 33
```

I want the program to start reading the scores  in each line but skip the blank spaces for example each record has a maximum of 4 scores however some records have less than 4 scores which are denoted by the whitespace i want the program to read these records skiping the white spaces i want this to be repeated until the end of file below is the code I have written for this part i am confused as to how i would proceed to do this any and all help is appreciated

Comment: ``std`::getline(file, line);)` What is this? Also, if you're looking to skip whitespace with getline you can say `std::getline(file>>std::ws, line);` This has to be a duplicate question, I'll see if I can dig it up.

Comment: @AndyG Doesn't `std::getline(file>>std::ws, line);` only trim leading white space?  I do not think it will ge rid of the white space between the name and the :.

Comment: @NathanOliver: That is correct. I suppose OP should decide between using a trim method like boost has, or to pass the record into a `std::stringstream` and continue the `stream >> std::ws` pattern. EDIT: Or perhaps I don't fully understand OPs requirement of "skipping the white spaces"

Comment: Do you actually have the blank lines in your file?

Comment: @NathanOliver:  sorry if i wasnt clear in my description the code given above reads the score above which have are maximum of 4 in each line however some lines have less than 4 and are left blank take saitama genos and goku black for example i want the program to skip these whitespaces however the program above replaces those whitespaces with the last score read

Comment: Do you _need_ to use `getline()`?

Comment: @FirstStep yes i would like to solve this problem with getline

Comment: @D-pag I get that.  I am asking if your actual file has the blank line between each record.  If it does that requires more handling.

Comment: @ NathanOliver oh no the actual textfile does not have a blank line between each record sorry for making this unclear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [std::getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) to greater advantage because it doesn't just get lines it will read up to a character you specify. For example the colon (`:`):

```
for(std::string line; std::getline(file, line);)
{
    // turn the line into a stream
    std::istringstream f(line);

    std::getline(f, line, ':'); // skip past ':'

    // read all the numbers one at a time
    for(int v; f >> v;)
        std::cout << v << ' ';

    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

**Output:**

```
2000 300 3000 300 

100 300 4000 900 



12 333 33
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change a couple of things about your program

- Use `std::ws` to efficiently discard newline characters between reads to `std::getline`:

  `for(std::string line; std::getline(file>> std::ws, line);)`
- Track how many values you were able to read into `value`:

  ```
  std::istringstream f(scores);
  size_t values_read = 0;
  while(f >> values[values_read] && ++values_read < 4)
  {
  }
  for (size_t i = 0; i < values_read; ++i)
      std::cout << values[i] << " ";
  std::cout << std::endl;
  ```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/17f3bfe4de79c7de)

Output:

> 2000 300 3000 300 
>   100 300 4000 900 
>   
>   12 333 33

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using the awesome `std::vector` from `#include <vector>` in something like this:

```
int main()
{
    string SampleStr = "2000 300 3000 300";
    vector<string> valuesSeperated;
    string temp;

    for(int i = 0; i < SampleStr.size(); i++)
    {
        if(SampleStr[i] == ' '|| SampleStr[i] == '\n')
        {
            valuesSeperated.push_back(temp);
            temp.clear();
        }
        else
            temp.push_back(SampleStr[i]);
    }
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Then put the whole thing in your for loop. Do it on each `getline()` and you will get `valuesSeperated` for each line.